# Short password for chromebook user, withouth having to use full google account password?

Tags: google-chrome-os, chromebook

Is there a way to be able to set a short memorable password for my chromebook user, rather than have to type my 50 character full alphanumeric password generated with by my password manager ?

Comment: does your password manager come with a chrome plugin and a master password? If so, you have your answer right in that password manager.

Comment: @LPChip: do chrome plugins work in the ChromeOS login screen?

Comment: That might be the only place where it doesn't work, actually...

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about the stable channel, but in the dev channel you can enable the pin login flag at `chrome://flags`

It doesn't work on the initial login, but is able to be used when the chromebook is locked

I will get you more info when I use my Chromebook again

Answer (score 3):

Enable two factor authentication for your Google account.  For ultimate security use a Yubikey.  Now you don't need the giant password.  Combine this with enabling PIN login as suggested by @DanHolli.

Also, Chromebooks use very little power with the lid closed. I leave mine on and therefore rarely have to log in.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [Smart Lock](https://get.google.com/smartlock/)? You just unlock your Chromebook when your unlocked Android device is near and has Bluetooth enabled.

Comment: Unfortunately we all use iOS devices, only "google" device on the network is this chromebook